# 6 months Passport Validity and Travel

Tags: passports, passport-renewals

This summer, my family (me, wife, and kid) is scheduled for a trip from the USA to India. The current passport of my kid (a US citizen) is valid till Dec 2022. Our return date in July 2022 is within the last 6 months window of the passport duration. However, the trip start date in early June is before the beginning of that 6 months window.

I am interested to renew my kid's passport, but I am not getting any passport appointments at any USPS even though I searched far-off locations.

Is it okay to travel with the current passport? Can there be any issue during the trip, particularly during the return? Could the airline (Singapore Airlines) refuse to board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no passport validity requirements when entering the country that the passport belongs to. In your kid's case, travelling to the US with a valid US passport (no matter how close to the expiration date) is perfectly okay. The airline should give you no trouble with that.

According to [travel.state.gov for India](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/India.html):

> PASSPORT VALIDITY:
>
> Must be valid for six months beyond date of visa application to obtain a visa.

According to [Transiting Through Singapore](https://safetravel.ica.gov.sg/transit/overview):

> As an illustration, if travellers intend to depart from Country X, transit in Singapore, and fly to destination Country Y, they are strongly advised to check the requirements of Country Y.

Comment: What about transit on the return journey?  What about entering India with the intention of departing less than six months before the passport's expiration?

Comment: @phoog: I added links to some supporting information.