# Passport validity requirement for traveling back to India

Tags: visas, passports, visa-expiration

I live in Australia. I am an Indian citizen and my kid's Indian passport is set to expire on 23/12/2024. I am planning to travel to India on December 20, 2024. Is it valid for me to travel to India or is there a six-month passport validity rule?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [6 months Passport Validity and Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173082/6-months-passport-validity-and-travel)

Comment: @Leaderboard That question is about *returning* to the US from India.

Comment: Do you plan to go back to Australia or to move back to India for a period of time. I don't think it's a problem to travel back to India (via a direct flight, if there is a connection then the transit rules for that country would apply). But you're not going to be able to come back to Australia with the kid and an expired passport and renewing the passport in India may be problematic if you don't have an address at which you live.

Comment: You've got _NINE_ months, start the passport renewal process _NOW_. You should be able to get it renewed by then. (Governments move slowly, I realize, but if you can _create_ a kid in 9 months, you should be able to renew his passport in that length of time). Since you're not living in your home country, keeping an up-to-date passport seems like it should be a pretty high priority...